# login to third party website using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have [URL](https://www.fastactportal.com/login)

and by viewing its source code i found the form used for login in this URL

```
<form name="frmLogin" action="j_spring_security_check" method="post"><!-- FORM START -->
                <div class="pod">
                    <div class="single_input">
                        <label class="label" for="j_username">User Name</label>
                        <div class="field">
                            <input type="text" id="j_username" name="j_username" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="single_input">
                        <label class="label" for="j_password">Password</label>
                        <div class="field">
                            <input type="password" id="j_password" name="j_password" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="single_input">

                        <div class="field">
                            <a href="externalResetPassword">Forgot Password</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="cta center">
                    <input name="btnContinue" type="submit" value="Login" class="btnContinue">
                </div>
            </form>
```

My question is, How can i check the user name and password i entered it correct without using browser. I hope i can do that using c# HttpWebRequest

**Edit:** I found some code that seems to be usefull but i am not understanding it properly

here is the code

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.fastactportal.com/login");
            req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)";
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5");
            req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate");
            req.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
            req.KeepAlive = true;
            req.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive: 300");
            req.Referer = "https://www.fastactportal.com/login";

            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            String Username = "j_username";
            String PassWord = "j_password";

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
            sw.Write("application=portal&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fastactportal.com%2Fportal%2Fredirect%3Bjsessionid%3D1C568AAA1FB8B5C757CF5F68BE6ECE65%3Ftype%3Dssologin%26url%3D%2Fportal%2Fshow%3Bjsessionid%3D1C568AAA1FB8B5C757CF5F68BE6ECE65%3Fidc%3D1023278&realm=sso&j_username=" + Username + "&j_password=" + PassWord + "&x=16&y=11");
            sw.Close();

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();


            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string tmp = reader.ReadToEnd();

            foreach (Cookie cook in response.Cookies)
            {
                tmp += "\n" + cook.Name + ": " + cook.Value;
            }


            Response.Write(tmp);
            Response.End();
```

this line very confusing

```
sw.Write("application=portal&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fastactportal.com%2Fportal%2Fredirect%3Bjsessionid%3D1C568AAA1FB8B5C757CF5F68BE6ECE65%3Ftype%3Dssologin%26url%3D%2Fportal%2Fshow%3Bjsessionid%3D1C568AAA1FB8B5C757CF5F68BE6ECE65%3Fidc%3D1023278&realm=sso&j_username=" + Username + "&j_password=" + PassWord + "&x=16&y=11");
```

Can anybody help me to understand this

Comment: yes, you may use HttpWebRequest

Answer (score 0):

Many web applications such as proxy web servers and multiple search engines are required to access the HTML pages of other websites. The classes `WebClient`, `WebRequest`, and `WebResponse` are usually used to perform these requirements in ASP.NET.

On the other hand, a `WebBrowser` control is used in a Windows Forms application to browse web pages and other browser-enabled documents. `WebBrowser` provides many events to track data processes, and many properties and methods to access and create new contents on the HTML element level.

In the bellow link i found the website which is using the window browser control

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50544/Using-the-WebBrowser-Control-in-ASP-NET